# Creating a new MS Access file in Java using Jackcess

Tags: java, database, exception, ms-access, jackcess

I have referred selected answer to this question: [Java: Create MSAccess Database File (.mdb 0r .accdb) using Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9543722/java-create-msaccess-database-file-mdb-0r-accdb-using-java).

I have MS Office 2010 in my machine. I am trying to create access database file (*.mdb / *.accdb). But, still the file is not getting created itself throwing following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: given file does not exist: C:\Users\473886\Desktop\employeedb1.mdb
    at com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.impl.DatabaseImpl.open(DatabaseImpl.java:360)
    at com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.DatabaseBuilder.open(DatabaseBuilder.java:170)
    at mdb.MDBWriter.createDatabase(MDBWriter.java:93)
    at mdb.MDBWriter.startDatabaseProcess(MDBWriter.java:107)
    at mdb.MDBWriter.main(MDBWriter.java:120)
```

I have used the same code available in the answer with one modification that I have used file dialog that will ask me where I want to save the database file:

```
public class MDBWriter {

    public static String saveFile(Frame f, String title, String defDir, String fileType) {
        FileDialog fd = new FileDialog(f, title, FileDialog.SAVE);
        fd.setFile(fileType);
        fd.setDirectory(defDir);
        fd.setLocation(50, 50);
        fd.show();
        return (fd.getDirectory() + "\\" + fd.getFile());
    }

    private static Database createDatabase(String databaseName) throws IOException {
//        return Database.create(new File(databaseName));
        File file = new File(databaseName);
        return new DatabaseBuilder(file)
        .setFileFormat(Database.FileFormat.V2010)
        .open();
    }

    private static TableBuilder createTable(String tableName) {
        return new TableBuilder(tableName);
    }

    public static void addColumn(Database database, TableBuilder tableName, String columnName, Types sqlType) throws SQLException, IOException {
        tableName.addColumn(new ColumnBuilder(columnName).setSQLType(Types.INTEGER).toColumn()).toTable(database);
    }

    public static void startDatabaseProcess() throws IOException, SQLException {
        String fileName = saveFile(new Frame(), "Save...", ".\\",   "*.mdb");
        String databaseName = "D:\\employeedb1.accdb"; // Creating an MS Access database
        Database database = createDatabase(fileName);

        String tableName = "Employee"; // Creating table
        Table table = createTable(tableName)
                .addColumn(new ColumnBuilder("Emp_Id").setSQLType(Types.INTEGER).toColumn())
                .addColumn(new ColumnBuilder("Emp_Name").setSQLType(Types.VARCHAR).toColumn())
                .addColumn(new ColumnBuilder("Emp_Employer").setSQLType(Types.VARCHAR).toColumn())
                .toTable(database);

        table.addRow(122875, "Sarath Kumar Sivan","Infosys Limited.");//Inserting values into the table
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, SQLException {
        startDatabaseProcess();
    }

}
```

Please suggest some solution.

Answer (score 1):

> No way to create [an Access database] from [Java] code !

Nonsense. The following works on any platform with Java and [Jackcess](http://jackcess.sourceforge.net/)...

```java
import com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.*;
import java.io.File;

public class bar {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            DatabaseBuilder.create(Database.FileFormat.V2010, new File("/home/gord/jTest.accdb"));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("Done!");
    }

}
```

..and the following code works in Java on Windows without Jackcess (but requires the Access Database Engine)...

```java
import java.io.*;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

public class CreateAccdb {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String databaseName = "C:\\__tmp\\employeedb1.accdb";

        String tempScriptName = System.getenv("TEMP") + "\\$$CreateAccdbScript.vbs";
        try {
            BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(tempScriptName));
            out.write("Set cat = CreateObject(\"ADOX.Catalog\")");
            out.newLine();
            out.write("cat.Create \"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + databaseName + ";\"");
            out.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        String cmd = "cscript " + tempScriptName;
        try {
            Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
            p.waitFor();
            BufferedReader rdr = 
                    new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getErrorStream()));
            int errorLines = 0;
            String line = rdr.readLine();
            while (line != null) {
                errorLines++;
                System.out.println(line);  // display error line(s), if any
                line = rdr.readLine();
            }
            if (errorLines == 0) {
                System.out.println("The operation completed successfully.");
            }
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            Files.deleteIfExists(Paths.get(tempScriptName));
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create a *new* database, you need to call `DatabaseBuilder.create()`, not `open()` (which opens an *existing* database).

Answer (score 0):

According to the answer [available here](http://objectmix.com/jdbc-java/41263-how-create-microsoft-access-database-mdb-java.html). The only solution is to copy an existing empty mdb, connect to this and create tables etc. No way to create a mdb from code !

Comment: According to the answer you have mentioned you can use DAO , ADOX to create DB

Comment: @4dmonster: That is not for java. That is for VB.

Comment: Is it impossible for java to create COM/ActiveX object on windows?