# How do I connect a MS Access database to Jetbrains DataGrip

Tags: ms-access, datagrip

I have been using DataGrip for a couple of weeks now and I like it a lot. 
The only thing I am unable to find out is how to connect DataGrip to a MS Access database.

Could someone explain to me how to do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per the [documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/datagrip/1.0/working-with-database-consoles.html?origin=old_help), MS Access is not supported yet.

> The following standardized and DBMS vendor-specific SQL dialects are
>   supported: DB2, Derby, H2, HSQLDB, MySQL, Oracle, Oracle SQL*Plus,
>   PostgreSQL, SQL Server, SQL92, SQLite, and Sybase .

Answer (score 35):

For Future readers this is still very doable (I'm on DataGrip version 208.1.4):

Get [UcanAccess](http://ucanaccess.sourceforge.net/)

1. Download and extract UcanAccess somewhere: `pathToUcanAccess`
2. In Datagrip goto add new connection: "Driver And Data source"

   - this will create a connection "Database Driver -" and a Driver "Database Driver"
3. Edit the newly created Driver "Database Driver":

   1. Under Additional Files add:

      - `<pathToUcanAccess>\ucanaccess-4.0.4.jar`
      - `<pathToUcanAccess>\lib\commons-lang-2.6.jar`
      - `<pathToUcanAccess>\lib\commons-logging-1.1.3.jar`
      - `<pathToUcanAccess>\lib\hsqldb.jar`
      - `<pathToUcanAccess>\lib\jackcess-2.1.11.jar`
   2. For Dialect select "SQL Driver"
   3. Hit Apply (this should load the classes from the added files)
   4. Under the class combo you should now see `net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver`, select it and hit apply again.
   5. Under Url templates add a new template, for name enter "default" for template enter `jdbc:ucanaccess://{file::identifier.sqlite};newdatabaseversion=V2010`
   6. Hit apply.
4. Now edit the database connection "Database Driver -":

   1. Next to the text box for url, in the drop down select default (or what ever you named the template in step 3.5)

      - A file select field should replace the previously visible "user" and "password" fields
   2. In the file selector, select your mdb

      - the url field should now look like `jdbc:ucanaccess://C:/data/MDBs/myMdbFile.mdb;newdatabaseversion=V2010`
   3. Hit apply and then ok.

You should see your Connection popup in the list, double-click to connect, expand it down the tree (`"Public \ <unnamed> \ tables"`) and you should see your tables.

Inspired by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26302542/476284).

Comment: Thanks a lot @GHayes, it still works fine with version 2018.2. You saved me a lot of time and pain. Thanks!

Comment: An update for 2021.1 would be useful, as I can find "additional files"...

Comment: I get this error when testing the connection `42581][-5581] UCAExc:::5.0.1 unexpected token: INTEGER required: FOR [42581][-5581] unexpected token: INTEGER required: FOR`

Answer (score 0):

You can try configuring MS Access as an ODBC source and then use a JDBC ODBC driver to connect to it, just like any other JDBC database.